# Simple javascript not working in Ionic 3 when viewing on localhost

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I am trying to get some really simple javascript to work in an ionic 3 app.  This js code works fine when I serve it to local host as a stand alone html file.  But when rendered with ionic, it is not working.  Any advice?

```
<ion-content padding> 

<div>
   <div class="inputoutput">
       <img id="imageSrc" alt="No Image" />
       <div class="caption">imageSrc <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let imgElement = document.getElementById("imageSrc")
    let inputElement = document.getElementById("fileInput");
    inputElement.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }, false);
</script>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Any erros displayed ? What is the result ?

Comment: When I select an image by browsing to it, the image should show up on the screen.  This works as expected when serving as a stand alone html file, but the image does not show up when serving as an ionic app.  No errors showing up in the chrome inspect tool

Comment: try removing the script tags out of the `<ion-content>`